# How can you transform a set of numbers into mostly whole ones?

Tags: c++, opengl, floating-point, double, discrete-mathematics

Small amount of background: I am working on a converter that bridges between a map maker [(Tiled)](http://www.mapeditor.org/) that outputs in XML, and an engine [(Angel2D)](https://github.com/Alicemargatroid/angel2d/tree/Development) that inputs lua tables. Most of this is straight forward

However, Tiled outputs in pixel offsets (integers of absolute values), while Angel2D inputs OpenGL units (floats of relative values); a conversion factor between these two is needed (for example, 32px = 1gu). Since OpenGL units are abstract, and the camera can zoom in or out if the objects are too small or big, the actual conversion factor isn't important; I could use a random number, and the user would merely have to zoom in or out.

But it would be best if the conversion factor was selected such that most numbers outputted were small and whole (or fractions of small whole numbers), because that makes it easier to work with (and the whole point of the OpenGL units is that they are easy to work with).

*How would I find such a conversion factor reliably?*

My first attempt was to use the smallest number given; this resulted in no fractions below 1, but often lead to lots of decimal places where the factors didn't line up.

Then I tried the mode of the sequence, which lead to the largest number of 1's possible, but often lead to very long floats for background images.

My current approach gets the GCD of the whole sequence, which, when it works, works great, but can easily be thrown off course by a single bad apple.

Note that while I could easily just pass the numbers I am given along, or pick some fixed factor, or use one of the conversions I specified above, I am looking for a method to reliably scale this list of integers to small, whole numbers or simple fractions, because this would most likely be unsurprising to the end user; this is not a one off conversion.

The end users tend to use 1.0 as their "base" for manipulations (because it's simple and obvious), so it would make more sense for the sizes of entities to cluster around this.

Comment: Just pass the integer values from Tiled directly into OpenGL. As long as the absolute values of integers are smaller than 2**23 you're not loosing information converting them into floats.

Comment: @datenwolf While that would work, it wouldn't really fit into the end users work flow or be "unsurprising".

Comment: How about figuring out some divisors that would be acceptable, and constructing a number that has them all as factors. What's needed is the smallest primes since composite numbers in between are products thereof. To consider them all for divisors simultaneously you could scale up the original numbers by a common factor of all the primes and run GCD on it, all the x's and all the y's. 2*3*5*7*11*13=30030, so scale everything by 30030 as an integer before running GCD. Then GCD(...) / 30030 is the fractional base you want to use. Note many numbers can be simplified further, i.e. 2/2 is 1.

Answer (score 2):

How about the 'largest number which is a factor of some % of the values'.
So the GCD is the 'largest number which is a factor of 100%' of the values.
You could pick the largest number which is a factor of, say 60%, of the values.  I don't know if it's a technical term but it's sort of a 'rough GCD if not a precise GCD'.

You might have to do trail and error to find it (possibly a binary search).  But you could also consider sampling.  I.e. if you have a million data points, just pick 100 or 1000 at random to find a number which divides evenly into your goal percentage of the sample set and that might be good enough.

some crummy pseudo C.

```
/** return percent of values in sampleset for which x is a factor */
double percentIsFactorOf(x, sampleset) {
  int factorCount = 0;

  for (sample : sampleset) 
     if (sample%x == 0) factorCount++;

  return (double)factorCount/sampleset.size;    
}

/** find largest value which is a factor of goalPercentage of sampleset */
double findGoodEnoughCommonFactor(sampleset, goalPercentage) {
   // slow n^2 alogrithm here - add binary search, sampling, or something smarter to improve if you like
   int start = max(sampleset);
   while (percentIsFactorOf(start, sampleset)< goalPercent)
     start--;
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but I was hoping for a more exact solution rather than an approximation or a brute force solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you are talking about with "GL units".

At the most abstract level, GL has no unit. Vertex coordinates are in object-space initially, and go through half a dozen user-defined transformations before they eventually produce coordinates (window-space) with familiar units (pixels).

You are absolutely correct that even in window-space, coordinates are still not whole numbers. You would not want this in fact, or triangles would jump all over the place and generally would not resemble triangles if their vertex positions were snapped to integer pixel coordinates.

Instead, GL throws sub-pixel precision into the mix. Coordinates still ultimately wind up quantized to integer values, but each integer may cover 1/256<sup>th</sup> of a pixel given 8-bit sub-pixel precision. Pixel coverage testing is done at the sub-pixel level as you can see here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC520311.png))</sub>

GL never attempts to find any conversion factor like you are discussing, it just splits the number space for pixel coordinates up into a fixed division between integral and fractional... ***fixed-point*** in other words. You might consider doing the same thing.

Comment: The function being called to set positions in OpenGL is (glTranslatef)[https://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glTranslate.html], which refers to X, Y, and Z coordinates. What exactly would you call 1 of these abstract unit? I've seen it called an OGL unit, and thought the terminology useful; the point is that I am starting from a concrete pixel based units and want to move to OpenGL's abstract units in as "unsurprising" a way as possible for the end user. I'd like the end user to deal with small numbers, basically.

Comment: @Alice: Those coordinates are unitless. `glTranslate (...)` applies to translation matrices. It multiplies the current matrix by another matrix, that applies translation. Since matrices are what define coordinate space transformations, the matrices themselves are unitless. The only time coordinates start being measured in terms of pixels (or any concrete unit for that matter) in GL is after the viewport transformation, prior to that a unit is anything you want it to be.

Comment: @Alice: If you are starting out with pixel units and want object-space coordinates to be whole numbers use an orthographic projection matrix and limit your scales to integer values. The only potentially funny thing here is that pixel centers are actually i + **0.5**. So a point at the center of a pixel (x,y) in window-space would be (x+0.5,y+0.5).

Answer (score 2):

If your input is in N^2 (two dimensional space over the field the natural numbers, i.e. non-negative integers), and you need to output to R^2 (two dimensional space over the field of real numbers, which in this case will be represented/approximated with a float).

Forget about scaling for a minute and let the output be of the same scale as the input. The first step is to realize that you the input coordinate <0, 0> does not represent <0, 0> in the output, it represents <0.5f, 0.5f>, the center of the pixel. Similarly the input <2, 3> becomes <2.5, 3.5>. In general the conversion can be performed like this:

```
float x_prime = (float)x + 0.5f;
float y_prime = (float)y + 0.5f;
```

Next, you probably want to pick a scaling factor, as you have mentioned. I've always found it useful to pick some real-world unit, usually meters. This way you can reason about other physical aspects of what you're trying to model, because they have units; i.e. speeds, accelerations, can now be in meters per second, or meters per second squared. How many meters tall or wide is the thing you are making? How many meters is a pixel? Pick something that makes sense, and then your formula becomes this:

```
float x_prime = ((float)x + 0.5f) * (float)units_per_pixel;
float y_prime = ((float)y + 0.5f) * (float)units_per_pixel;
```

You may not want all of your output coordinates to be in the positive quadrant; that is you may want the origin to be in the center of the object. If you do, you probably want your starting coordinate system's field to include negative integers, or provide some offset to the true center. Lets say you provide a pixel offset to the true center. Your conversion then becomes this:

```
float x_prime = ((float)x + 0.5f - (float)x_offset) * (float)units_per_pixel;
float y_prime = ((float)y + 0.5f - (float)y_offset) * (float)units_per_pixel;
```

Comment: This is an excellent analysis, but the problem is I am writing a tool; your middle step (pick something that makes sense), is something I can't have knowledge of. While I do allow the end user to pick a conversion factor that makes sense to them, I want the default to be a method which finds a conversion factor that leads mostly to small, whole numbers, which are likely to be unsurprising.

Comment: @Alice: Then for a default scale, here is what I would suggest trying: Scaling numbers otherwise between 0 and 1 to 0 to 100, this is how percentages work and the general consensus is that they are intuitive. The straight-forward way to do this is to scale by a factor of 100/max(magnitude(all_points)). However outliers will mess you up. You might try throwing away the top 10% of magnitudes and taking the max of that, i.e. 100 divided by the 90th percentile magnitude.

Comment: But I guess that doesn't really address the whole number thing. However, to me I would think the values would be more intuitive if in a well understood range like 0 to 100, than by eliminating the presence of fractional parts.

Answer (score 2):

Discarding your background information, I understand that the underlying problem you are trying to solve is the following:

Given a finite number of (positive) integers {x_1, ... x_N} find some (rational) number f such that all x_i / f are "nice".

If you insist on "nice" meaning integer and as small as possible, then f = GCD is the (mathematically) exact  answer to this question. There just is nothing "better", if the GCD is 1, tough luck.

If "nice" is supposed to mean rational with small numerator and denominator, the question gets more interesting and depending on what "small" means, find your trade off between small absolute value (f = max) and small denominator (f = GCD). Notice, however, that small numerator/denominator does not mean small floating point representation, e.g. 1/3 = 0.333333... in base 10.

If you want short [floating points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), make sure that f is a power of your base, i.e. 10 or 2, depending on whether the numbers should look short to the user or actually have a reasonable machine representation. This is what is used for [scientific representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) of floating points, which might be the best answer to the question of how to make decimal numbers look nice in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can recycle the code you probably currently use for vector normalisation, normalise the values to fit within a max. value of 1; for example:

the formula for 3d normalisation of a vector works fine here
Get the length first:

```
|a| = sqrt((ax * ax) + (ay * ay) + (az * az))
```

Then you will need to divide the values of each component by the length:

```
x = ax/|a|
y = ay/|a|
z = az/|a|
```

Now all the `x, y, z` values will fall into the maxima of -1 to 1, the same as the OpenGL base coordinate system.

I know this does not generate the whole numbers system you would like, however it does give a smaller more unified feel to the range.

Say you want to limit the range to whole numbers only, simply use a function like the following, which will take the normalised value and convert it to an int-only range value:

```
#include <algorithm>    // this allows the use of std::min
int maxVal = 256
unsigned char convertToSpread(float floatValueToConvert){
    return (unsigned char) (std::min((maxVal-1), (int) (floatValueToConvert * maxVal)));
}
```

The above will spread your values between 0 and 255, simply increase the value of `maxVal` to what you need and change the `unsigned char` to a datatype which suits your needs.
So if you want 1024 values, simply change `maxVal` to 1024 and `unsigned char to`unsigned int`

Hope this helps, however, let me know if you need more information as well, and I can elaborate:)